# Format blank columns based on number of rows in spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I'm attempting to color code blank columns in a worksheet based on the number of rows I have in my data set.  I have an existing macro that sorts and formats my data but I want to add code to do this piece.  The number of rows could vary from 50-50,000 and I don't want to color the entire column down to the bottom of the sheet.  Is there a way to do this with vba code?
I've tried this code but it colors the entire column, not just the 100 rows I have.

```
Range(Range("H13"), Range("H13").End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
       Selection.Interior.Color = vbBlue
```

Answer (score 1):

You're close

```
Sub test()
Dim lrow As Integer
lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
Range("H13:H" & lrow).Interior.Color = vbBlue
End Sub
```

You're using xldown, which is taking the last cell and then going down to the end of the sheet. Try using xlup. Also - try to get out of the habit of using `selection` - it's usually never necessary.